# Malayalam epub to Kindle format

Tags: kindle, epub, fonts

There are some good Malayalam books in DCBooks for purchase. It's in epub format. Have to use DCBooks ebook reader application to read. I don't like to read in mobile ... I want this in Kindle.

I tried to convert to .mobi and to .Azw3 Cannot read... looks unsupported font...

Inside the folder along with .epub I noticed few html, jpg and some fonts (.otf in a folder).

Any one tried to read those in Kindle...?

Comment: try searching for epub to mobi convert in current website, there are already answers  for your question. You can try Calibre or online websites such as: www.epubconverter.com/epub-to-mobi-converter/

Comment: @ Woeitg: _try searching for epub to mobi convert in current website_ The old MOBI format **does not** support Indic languages. However, the new AZW3 format does.

Comment: I tried Calibre. Even in Calibre I cannot read... Looks like it is encrypted font ! or I dont know .. Its in Epub but can read only with this application ..
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dcbooks.ebookreader&hl=en

Comment: @akinsg I have purchased some books from ebooks.dcbooks.com. But where I  can find the epub file in mobile ?

Comment: Facing the same issue. Its something with dcbooks app is not writing the entire file contents to the epub file you can find in the system directory. The app might be "unencrypting" the content on the fly when one reads using app. Couldn't find any trick to unencrypt or make the epub work from the disk file

Comment: Tried editing (Calibre) the epub file and look in the META-INF folder and delete the encryption.xml file. Thought that will take care of font encryption. It still giving problems.
I tried deleting the font files and just replacing them with the font files from your font library.
I guess the content is still encrypted. Wondering if we can catch what kind of encryption is used and how decrypt it properly

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what Kindle platform you are aiming for, Kindle E-ink, tablet or app.

I created a sample `epub` file using [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/). The source in markdown is as follows:

```
---
author: Khalid
title: Malayalam Test
---

# ‘ദൃഷ്ടിച്ചാവേര്‍’

മലയാളത്തിലെ ആദ്യ ചെറുകഥ ഏത് എന്ന ചോദ്യത്തിന്
ഒറ്റ ഉത്തരമേയുള്ളു. അത് വേങ്ങയില്‍
കുഞ്ഞിരാമന്‍നായനാരുടെ
‘വാസനാവികൃതി’യാണ്.
1891 ല്‍ രചിച്ച ആ ചെറുകഥ
പ്രസിദ്ധീകരിച്ചിട്ട് ഇപ്പോള്‍
125 വര്‍ഷങ്ങള്‍ പിന്നിടുകയാണ്.
വാസനാവികൃതിയുടെ 125 -ാം പിറന്നാള്‍ വിപുലമായി
ആഘോഷിക്കാന്‍ തീരുമാനിച്ചിരിക്കുകയാണ്
പ്രതിമാസ പുസ്തക ചര്‍ച്ചാവേദിയായ ഡി
സി റീഡേഴ്‌സ് ഫോറം.

# വാസനാവികൃതിയുടെ

ഡി സി ബുക്‌സ് കഥാഫെസ്റ്റ് പരമ്പരയില്‍
ഉള്‍പ്പെടുത്തി പ്രസിദ്ധീകരിച്ച പി ജിംഷാറിന്റെ
പടച്ചോന്റെ ചിത്രപ്രദര്‍ശനം, ദേവദാസ് വി.എമ്മിന്റെ
അവനവന്‍ തുരുത്ത്, വി എച്ച് നിഷാദിന്റെ ആതിരാ
സൈക്കിള്‍, കെ വി മണികണ്ഠന്റെ ബ്ലൂ ഈസ് ദ
വാമെസ്റ്റ് കളര്‍, അബിന്‍ ജോസഫിന്റെ കല്യാശ്ശേരി
തീസിസ്, ലാസര്‍ ഷൈന്റെ കൂ , ധന്യാരാജിന്റെ
പദപ്രശ്‌നം, കെ ഇ ഷീബയുടെ കനലെഴുത്ത് എന്നീ
പുസ്തകങ്ങളും എന്‍ പ്രഭാകരന്റെ മനസ്സ് പോകുന്ന
വഴിയേ എന്ന കഥാസമാഹാരവുമാണ്
പരിചയപ്പെടുത്തുന്നത്.
```

I then converted the resultant `epub` file to `mobi` using [Kindlegen](https://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1000765211). The Kindle Previewer has no problem rendering Malayalam:

[image: Kindle Previewer Malayalam Test]

On my Kindle Paperwhite 3, I get the following,

[image: Malayalam on Paperwhite 3]