# How to upload my Malayalam book in Kindle?

Tags: kindle, file-format, fonts

I have published books in Malayalam language through Creative Space.

Now I know that kindle is accepting Malayalam language books and when I try to upload the files (as per KDP they need docx file), Kindle is not accepting and rejects the book with an error. I have tried many times and received the same error which says: to check the file.

I think that the 'font' of my file is not accepted by Kindle.

What type of file format is required in Kindle?

Comment: See this related help topic https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/how-to-perfectly-convert-and-read-malayalam-ebooks-on-kindle

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the precise answer to your question and you probably have more experience formatting in your native language.

My guess is that doing a conversion from DOCX to Kindle or DOCX to epub will be horrible. MS Office will probably specify its own font, and then Kindle won't support it or allow it to be embedded.

Here is a better strategy. Focus on producing an epub file which validates as EPUB 3 http://validator.idpf.org/ If it validates, my guess is that it will also render easily on Kindle if you convert from epub to Kindle using Kindle Beta Previewer. https://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1003018611

The work processes (and the necessary steps) for producing a kindle/epub file are a lot different for creating a Createspace printed book. What works in Createspace will probably not work for Kindle and vice versa.

To produce a good epub/kindle file, you should probably create the content using an HTML/epub editor. Try using either of these two (free) products:

1. Calibre's EPUB editor (which is different from the Calibre
   conversion part). See https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/edit.html

   or
2. sigil epub editor.

The one thing I do not know is if the included Kindle fonts include support for Malayam characters. If you have heard that they do, then it should be easy.

If not, then you will have to embed a special Malayam font yourself. This is not extremely difficult, but it is complicated. See https://kindlegen.s3.amazonaws.com/AmazonKindlePublishingGuidelines.pdf Chapter 9 .

Good luck, and try to tell us what worked for you!

Comment: **@idiotprogrammer:** All current eInk Kindle models come with the Indic Noto Sans fonts. I.e., the OP shouldn't have to embed any font. 

**@Ignatius Variath:** Remove all fonts and make sure that the epub is encoded in UTF-8. Many Indic books are encoded in [ISCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Script_Code_for_Information_Interchange) and require matching fonts. If the ebook looks like garbage after removing the fonts, it wasn't encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Nemo xxx. Very interesting. I have been compiling a list of default fonts for reading systems  https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/7143/what-are-serif-and-sans-serif-fonts-on-different-ebook-reading-systems and I had no idea that font installations differed by region. I updated the information to include that. Also, I have to wonder when  Google Play Books will start using it!

Comment: I encourage you (or anyone) to check my list of system fonts for various reading systems and add corrections/updates in the comments. ( https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/7143/what-are-serif-and-sans-serif-fonts-on-different-ebook-reading-systems )

Answer (score 0):

First convert all text into Malayalam Unicode fonts like Mangal or Karthika. Then format the book in Word, upload, and it will be accepted.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1. Use Calibre to convert your books format to AZW3
2. Upload converted book to your Kindle.

Comment: **@Gil:** KDP won't accept Calibre generated AZW3 files.

Comment: @Nemo XXX: Did you use Calibre to upload converted AZW3 file to KDP?

Comment: **@Gil:** _Did you use Calibre to upload converted AZW3 file to KDP?_ No, because Amazon KDP won't accept AZW3 files.